# Unrecognized VM option UseContainerSupport

Tags: java, java-11

When I run my spring boot application on Java 11 with the following command, it reports error.

```
$ java -jar -XX:+UseContainerSupport tmall-content-gateway-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Unrecognized VM option 'UseContainerSupport'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My java version:

```
$ java --version
java 11.0.17 2022-10-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269, mixed mode)
```

Comment: `-jar` should be followed by the jar file or in other words, JVM options should be placed before the `-jar` option.

Comment: Also, if used `-jar <JAR-file>` must be the **last** option, everything after is interpreted as arguments to the program launched by the JAR. I'm surprised it doesn't produce a different error, but maybe the argument parser is more lenient than the documented syntax.

Comment: Yes. The options should be placed before `-jar` according to oracle doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html.

it's surprising that java accepts the option even when I put it after `-jar`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. it's not working on MacBook.

> This support is only available on Linux x64 platforms.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE

Comment: And on Linux x64 it is enabled *by default* so `-XX:+UseContainerSupport` would be redundant.